# Finding parent of highcharts button w/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a button in my highcharts chart that uses the following code:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        backButton: {
            _titleKey: 'backTitle',
            enabled: theChart.buttonOn,
            x: 0,
            y: 300,
            onclick: function () {
                $(this).parents(".chart").data('chart', $(this).parents(".chart").data('mainChart'));
                $(this).parents(".chart").trigger('redoChart');
            },
            text: 'Click to return to full graph',
            width:200,
            theme: {
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: 'black',
                fill: '#cccccc',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'black',
                        fill: '#cccccc'
                    },
                    select: {
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'black',
                        fill: '#cccccc'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on this button, nothing happens. I've determined that it is because `$(this).parents(".chart")` is not appropriately identifying the container div for my chart (which does have the class "chart"). If I replace `$(this).parents(".chart")` with `$("#thechart")`, everything is fine.

Comment: We need to see the HTML and what `this` refers to. Also, if your chart has an ID, use it.

Comment: My assumption is that `this` refers to the button since this is the "on click" function for the button... is that incorrect?

Comment: It probably does, if you could post the HTML containing that button and your chart we could verify

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ztfRS/1/

There's a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem. If we can get the div to hide there, I can implement the solution in my application.

Comment: First of all, in this you have chart object, secondly what you need to hide? entire chart ? if yes, why you cannot use $('#chartDiv').hide() ?

Comment: Certainly `$('#chartDiv').hide()` would work, but I'm using this in a situation where I need to have buttons on multiple charts that are loaded via queries for JSON... it would take a long time to explain, but essentially, I can't reference it based on the div.

You say the chart object is in `this`? If that's true, why can the div not be found in the list of parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this.container).parents('.chart').hide();
```

In the button handler `this` is a highcharts object.  `this.container` is the highcharts created div within your div.  So, to hide the whole thing, you're looking up to the parent that you added a chart class to.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Do you mind explaining what's going on or why this works?